# EGARCH(1,1) mean

Tags: garch

I'm trying to model an EGARCH(1,1). However, I dont understand why the mean from the general to (1,1) becomes $\sqrt{(\frac{2}{\pi})}$.

The following I am refering to is:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is because $|z_t|$ is a standard half-normal random variable and have expectation $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

**The expectation, $\mathbb{E}\left[|z_t|\right] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ is true, when $z_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,1)$**. In this case, the absolute value of $z_t$ is called a (standard) half-normal variable that has known expectation. You can verify this from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). If $z_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $\mathbb{E}\left[|z_t|\right]=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't actually know, that when you take the absolute value of the expectations, the variable is referred to as a half-normal variable.

Comment: @SebastianStraussHansen, the distribution is actually called [Folded normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).

Comment: @RichardHardy Indeed. The half-normal distribution is a special case of the Folded normal distribution when $\mu = 0$, which is also described in your link. :-)